# Is there a way to generate a octagon-hexagon-square-trapezoid grid in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Ok, I am attempting to make a game in Python using Pygame I want a grid look like the image below;

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdmLZ.png]

I don't even know how to approach this, any help would be greatly appreciated. (Also a detailed explanation would be helpful as I am a novice.)

Thank you.

I don't even know how to approach this

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I highly suggest doing some more research about pygame, if you have no idea how to approach the issue then it probably means you should first learn how to use the necessary tools.

If you want to build a game, I suggest not jumping straight into it and learning the ropes of python and pygame before you start building. If you just want the image to be displayed without any interactivity or animation (I'm assuming you want to add that on later?) you can try this code:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

image_path = "path/to/your/image.jpg"  # Replace with the path to your image file
image = pygame.image.load(image_path)
image_rect = image.get_rect()

width, height = image_rect.width, image_rect.height
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame Image Display")


screen.blit(image, image_rect)

pygame.display.flip()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
```

These are basic pygame functions, blit simply draws the image onto the screen. The while loop detects if you quit the GUI and it will end. You can try customising the image dimensions if you want or you want to have another grid.

Again, you should probably try to learn some more of pygame, since this is just a small script without much functionality other than the display you wanted